# Proving that in a homeomorphism, the number of components are same and the components are homeomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

Our professor of Topology gave the following theorem to prove:

> Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous. Then the image of each component of $X$ must lie in a component of $Y$.
> Further if $h: X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism then $h$ induces a $1-1$ correspondence between the components of $X$ and those of $Y$, corresponding ones being homeomorphic.

He gave the proof as follows:

*Proof::*
Let $C_x$ be a component of $X$ containing $x \in X$. Then $C_{x}$ is connected and so $f\left(C_{x}\right)$ is a connected set containing $f(x)=y \in Y$. So $f\left(C_{x}\right) \subset C_{y}$ as $C_{y}$ is a connected component of $y \in Y$ which is a maximal connected set containing $y$.

Next, let $h: X \rightarrow Y$ be a homeomorphism. Let $C_{x}$ and $C_{y}$ be component of $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ resp.

As $h$ is bijective for $y \in Y$ ,$ \exists x \in X$ s.t. $h(x)=y$
Now $h\left(C_{x}\right) \subset C_{y}$
and $\quad{h}^{-1}\left(C_{y}\right) \subset C_{x}$ so that $h\left(C_{x}\right) =C_{y}$
Thew $\left.h\right|_{C_{x}}: C_{x} \rightarrow C_{y}$ is a homeomorphism
and $\quad C_{x} \rightarrow C_{h(x)}$ gives $1-1$ correspondence between the components of $X$ and those of $Y$.
This is the end of the proof.

But I was wondering whether for showing the second part i.e. to show the 1-1 correspondence between the components of X and Y, it is sufficient to show that under a homeomorphism, component of X is mapped to a component of Y?
Don't I need to show a bijection between the set of all components of X and set of all components of Y?
And what should I do for the homeomorphic part i.e. components are homeomorphic?

**My attempt:**
I tried by defining and map
$\phi: S_X \rightarrow S_Y$ by $\phi(C_x)=h(C_x)$, where,
$S_X$ and $S_Y$  are the set of all components of X and Y respectively.
Then I showed that $h(C_x)$ is indeed a component of Y by showing $h(C_x)=C_y$, where $y=h(x)$.
I am stuck at showing one one and onto.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think that what your professor wrote is fine but, for your attempt, consider defining an inverse for your map $\phi$ (hint: use that $h$ has continuous inverse). This will prove one-one and onto

Comment: @Aitor Why the proof given by my professor is sufficient?